# MVVM: How to declare columnShow event handler using attributes?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

columnShown is an event being triggered when a column is shown uing the column menu (ref. in kendoui documentation to the event can be seen [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-columnShow))

My question is how to set that event listner in MVVM way, using declarative approach?

I tried (without any luck) so far those two approaches:

```
data-bind='source: dataSource, events:{ columnShow: onColumnShow}'>
```

and this one

```
 data-column-show = function(e) { console.log(e.column.field); }
```

In both cases - nothing happens when I use column menu to show originally hidden column.

Anyone knowing the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the events binding should have worked. The following snippet works as expected:

```
<div id="grid" data-column-menu="true"     
  data-role="grid"     
  data-bind="source: items, events: { columnShow: columnShow }">
</div>
<script>
kendo.bind(document.body, {
  items: [
    { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" }
  ],
  columnShow: function(e) {
    alert(e.column.field);
  }
});
</script>
```

Here is a live demo on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ahagit/1/edit